# How to covert a 9 digit number into 128bit, 192bit, 256bit key

Tags: php

I am trying to generate encryption key of 128,192,256 bits.

I have a number, suppose that is 965276154.

I want to convert this number into a large string into 128,192,256 bit keys

Comment: What  exactly are you trying to accomplish? Without m ore information this question will probably be closed soon as to broad. Please edit the question  and add enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. By accepting a answer you are indicating to future readers that it is a correct answer.

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) (Key Derivation Function) such as [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) to create an encryption key.

Each side will have to agree on a salt value and roud count but these do not need to be secret.

**But** this seems suspect, it is better and more secure to use well vetted standard methods such as TLS/HTTPS.

Obligatory: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*"

Comment: PBKDF2 allows upto 160 bit key generation

Comment: @SohailSaif PBKDF1 only allowed up to 160 bit key generation, PBKDF2 does not have that limitation.